# dName should show "Beta", but for some reason it's showing "kamran2", Why?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm practicing static classes and data members. I have created a static string(name) and the giving it a value in 2 different methods. One is walking(non-static) and the other is talking(static).Now in the main method when I call "dName", it should give me the value I initiated in "talking" method but it's not giving me that.

```
class Human{
        int age;
        double height;
        static String name;
        
        public void walking(){
            System.out.println("This person can walk");
            name = "Alpha";
        }
        
        public static void talking(){
            System.out.println("This person can talk");
            name = "Beta";
        }
    }
    
    public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
          Human kamran = new Human();
          Human adnan = new Human();
          
          kamran.name = "kamran";
          adnan.name = "kamran2";
          
          String dName = kamran.name;
          
          kamran.walking();
          kamran.talking();
          
          
          System.out.println(adnan.name);
          System.out.println(dName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are going to work with static members and methods then you should access them in a static way and not use objects. Like `Human.name = "Kamran"`

Comment: Run your code using the debugger of your IDE and see what the value of variable `name` is before and after you run each line of code that modifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Here, 'name' is a static field on Human class. So by your design you are giving all humans same name, because static field belongs to the class and not instances.

Also, dName is being set before calling kamran.talking(). Set it after the method call and you'll get ouput "Beta"

For better understanding I've modified your code. It works the same.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
          Human kamran = new Human();
          Human adnan = new Human();
          
          Human.name = "kamran";
          Human.name = "kamran2";
          
          String dName = kamran.name;
          System.out.println(dName); //kamran2  <==
          
          kamran.walking();
          Human.talking();
          
          dName = kamran.name; //Beta <==
                    
          System.out.println(adnan.name);
          System.out.println(dName);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because you assign the value before execute the method talking.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
      Human kamran = new Human();
      Human adnan = new Human();
      
      kamran.name = "kamran";
      adnan.name = "kamran2";
        String dName = kamran.name;
      kamran.walking();
      kamran.talking();
      
      
      System.out.println(adnan.name);
      System.out.println(dName);
}
```